# Bezier freehand draw curve is very coarse with larger errors

Tags: bezier-curves

When creating a freehand drawing of a Bezier curve i get very coarse angular line with an "error" of ~10 in the "Draw Curve" menu (see image). [image: Choppy angular bezier curve]

When opening a new Blender window the curve draws fine (see second image):

[image: smooth bezier curve]

Any ideas how to fix this large error in the first example? Note, This occurs after import of a raster image using the BlenderGIS plugin.

MacOSX
Blender 2.78

Comment: Looking at this in more detail I found that this is a scale dependent issue, when I am zoomed far out ~km scale i get the very coarse lines in first image, when zoomed in, I get the nice smooth lines.

Comment: You have a few options in the toolbar Options tab under Curve Stroke.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a small bug perhaps, I closed blender and restarted and it is no longer a problem.